# Get IP address on Django-channels - on receive handler

Tags: python, django, django-channels

We get the IP address of web socket client as `message.content["client"]` in the `connect` handler. but this code fails in `receive` handler. Is there any way we can get the IP address of client in `receive` handler ?

**Edit:**

In 'dphane/ws_protocol.py', in class `WebSocketProtocol` I see that in `onconnect`, the code is

```
        self.request_info = {
            "path": self.unquote(self.path),
            "headers": self.clean_headers,
            "query_string": self._raw_query_string,  # Passed by HTTP protocol
            "client": self.client_addr,
            "server": self.server_addr,
            "reply_channel": self.reply_channel,
            "order": 0,
        }

        ...
        ...

        self.channel_layer.send("websocket.connect", self.request_info)
```

where as in `onmessage`, the code is

```
        if isBinary:
            self.channel_layer.send("websocket.receive", {
                "reply_channel": self.reply_channel,
                "path": self.unquote(self.path),
                "order": self.packets_received,
                "bytes": payload,
            })
        else:
            self.channel_layer.send("websocket.receive", {
                "reply_channel": self.reply_channel,
                "path": self.unquote(self.path),
                "order": self.packets_received,
                "text": payload.decode("utf8"),
            })
```

We are not getting the client ip because Dphane is not giving that information in `message` handler.

Is there any way other than inheriting class WebSocketProtocol & overriding onmessage

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it using request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is still a problem, but you should look into getting the 
message.content["client"] into the session.
So when you get your message you can retrieve the IP in the session.